# How to get Hex String of Storage File in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, pdf, hex, windows-phone-8.1, local-storage

I am getting images using PhotoChooser and CameraCapture Taks,

I am storing these images in Local Storage and in the form of **"PDF Document"**.

My aim is that, I have to add this document in **"Hex String"**. I am able to convert it into
Hex String but not properly.

**Because, after adding PDF Document, when I see that document in my phone, it is something other document.**

**Here is my ByteArray:**

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
WriteableBitmap wbitmp = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)image1.Source);
wbitmp.SaveJpeg(ms, 400, 400, 0, 100);
bytearray = ms.ToArray();
```

**Now, creating it to Local Storage:**

```
StorageFolder folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile sampleFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync("Test.pdf", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(sampleFile, bytearray);
```

**Then trying to Convert it to MemoryStream:**

```
MemoryStream itsStream = new MemoryStream();
var outputStream = await sampleFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
Stream longStream = outputStream.AsStream();
longStream.CopyTo(itsStream);

byte[] allInOne = itsStream.ToArray();
```

**Here is my final HexString of "PDF Document":**

```
string hexString = BitConverter.ToString(allInOne);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!!

Comment: You are not storing the images as PDF file. Simply naming the file test.pdf and writing some content to it does not make it a valid PDF file.

Comment: @iPDFdev yes, but do you know how to convert image files to pdf files. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the way. I have added ComponentOne Library in Windows Phone 8.1 Project.

```
using C1.Phone.Pdf;
using C1.Phone.PdfViewer;

C1PdfDocument pdf = new C1PdfDocument(PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber3Rotated);
pdf.Landscape = true;

var rc = new System.Windows.Rect(20,30,300,200);
pdf.DrawImage(wbitmp, rc);

var fillingName = "Test.pdf";
var gettingFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

using (var loadingFinalStream = gettingFile.CreateFile(fillingName))
{
   pdf.Save(loadingFinalStream);
   MemoryStream leadingMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
   loadingFinalStream.Position = 0;
   loadingFinalStream.CopyTo(leadingMemoryStream);
   byte[] leadingBytes = leadingMemoryStream.ToArray();
   lastHexString = BitConverter.ToString(leadingBytes);
}
```